# Deserialize and access CS:GO JSON array in vb.net

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

some awesome dude put out the CS:GO skins data out as JSON.

http://api.ncla.me/data/data.json

But I am really struggling to deserialize it and access the individual items. 
Could you guys help? Is it possible without third-party additions? ( I don't care how fast or slow it is. )

This is how far I have come

```
Public Class RootObject

    Public Property ResultList_Main As List(Of ListWrapper_Main)

    Public Class ListWrapper_Main
        Public Property WeaponInfo As List(Of ListWrapper)
    End Class

    Public Class ListWrapper
        Public Property value As String
        Public Property quantity As String
    End Class
End Class


    jsonObject = jsSerializer.Deserialize(Of RootObject)(responseFromServer)

    For Each Itemdetail1 In jsonObject.ResultList_Main
        For Each Itemdetail2 In Itemdetail1.WeaponInfo
            'Would like to display WeaponInfo + Value + Quantity here
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, what error?

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." At this line: "For Each Itemdetail1 In jsonObject.ResultList_Main"